# How to implement a rich text document store in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ckeditor

I need a tiny (less than 100 total) document store in a Rails 3.2 app where a user can create, edit, save, and delete rich text documents (ideally including images and other attached items).  There is no file system available.  Everthing must go in PostgreSQL database tables.  The documents will serve as system-wide email and message banner templates.

My approach has been CKEditor.  But the [`ckeditor` gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) seems wired for attachments as files.  Also, it does not provide create/update storage of the document itself, just attachments.

I know how to roll my own model/controller/view the CKEditor but surely there's a simpler way.

So what is the most direct way to my goal of the rich text document store?  Is there a plugin or gem?

More CKEditor references: [This thread](http://ckeditor.com/comment/60207) makes it look like a major project, but it's 2 years old. [This one makes it sound](http://www.question2answer.org/qa/13219/upload-images-instead-database-possible-recommended-ckeditor) like the default, but no other document does.

**More**

Using S3, Dropbox as suggested are also nogo.  As I said, data must reside in PgSQL tables.  Good news: found the `paperclip_database` gem.  Bad news: doesn't work seamlessly with the `ckeditor` gem.  The main issue boils out to this bit in the source file `database.rb`:

```
  def setup_paperclip_files_model
    #TODO: This fails when your model is in a namespace.
```

Indeed it does, as in the `Ckeditor::Asset` model!  Trying a monkey patch now.  If anyone has already made these three gems work together correctly, I'll give you the bounty for a pointer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure CKEditor makes it fairly simple to edit database form fields, which is all you'd need for editing the document itself, correct?

As far as attachment storage, you can use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to manage the attachments -- file storage is just the default.  If you use paperclip, you can then use one of many storage options from there, such as Amazon S3 storage, [Dropbox](https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox), or create your own.

Hope that helps.

Comment: As I said, data needs to go in PgSQL tables. However +1 because the idea of looking for another storage connector in a gem led me to `paperclip_database`.  It doesn't quite work, but getting close...

Comment: Another one is: https://github.com/patshaughnessy/paperclip.  If that doesn't work, his website has examples of how to roll your own.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The first thread you linked to has it correctly: you need to (find or) write a custom server connector, and configure CKEditor to use it. You can find the relevant updated docs here:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api

Comment: Thanks.  Writing custom code is what I'm trying to avoid. The `ckeditor` rails support gem has a nice browser for attachments with Paperclip.  Hope to use this. Will of course fall back to custom code if necessary.